# Switching between telnet and ftp connections in the same window

Tags: c#, ftp, cmd, telnet

HI my job is to fetch some files thro telnet and ftp protocols,
I am just using command prompt to type the commands

I would usually login to telnet and type the telnet commands thro 1 command prompt window.
For executing ftp commands i would create a new command prompt window.

My question here is

Is there a way by which i could execute telnet and ftp commands in the same window. I am finding an option MULTINET in telnet help .will this serve this purpose?

If available, can the same procedure be used in C# telnet fetching operations using tcpclient by sending appropriate commands?

Assuming 2nd qn is possible? in this scenario how to handle the ending of ftp and telnet sessions (i.e relogin scenarios) ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to pull the files to the local PC using FTP. Otherwise you could push them from the remote server inside your telnet session.

One way you can do this is to escape your telnet session then try to run external ftp commands from your telnet client. Once the ftp command is done you can return to your telnet session. This assumes that your telnet client can run external commands.

When you open a telnet session you will see something like:

```
Escape character is '^]'.
```

When you press the escape character (Control ]) you escape the telnet session. It is still open but depending on the telnet client you can interact with your local PC.

On most Unix clients you can invoke a command in a subshell by prefixing the command with an exclamation mark:

```
!ftp
```

Once the FTP command is done you can return to the telnet session.

Telnet and FTP are two different protocols that run on different ports. So you can create a C# program that issues telnet commands to one port (typically port 23) and the same program can also send FTP commands to another port (typically ports 20 and 21). The telnet and FTP sessions are separate so you need to manage them separately.